# React universal redux-saga memory leak

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, server-side-rendering

I am working on a React isomorphic app that uses redux and redux-saga.
My problem is that the node process that runs the app takes more and more memory as requests get processed, until it eventually runs out of memory.

I profiled the app with `node --inspect` and noticed that the saga library keeps creating `(array)` type references in memory that never get cleared, even after garbage collection runs.

To test the issue, run this project and profile it with chrome-devtools:
https://github.com/MartinCerny-awin/isomorphic-react-redux-saga-ssr

(not my project, but it seems to behave the same way)

[image: Heap Snapshot]
You can see these objects in the heap diff: 
`updateState in system / Context @1770579` `context in cancel()`

I have tried binding the redux store and the saga middleware to the express `response`, thinking that it was a request namespace issue, but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> Redux saga [task cancellation](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.md) will prevent memory leaks.

**CANCEL SAGAS ON COMPONENT UNMOUNT/ROUTE CHANGE**

I think the issue is that you are not cancelling the sagas after the component associated with the saga unmounts. This could lead to a memory leak as the saga keeps waiting for an action and doesn't terminate.

```
    import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
    // other imports

    function* rootSaga() {
      const watcher = yield [
        takeLatest(GET_TODO, getToDoSaga),
        // your other sagas
      ];

      // the saga gets cancelled when your route changes. Instead 
      // a custom action can also be dispatched from your
      // componentWillUnMount of ToDo component
      yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE); 
      yield watcher.map((task) => cancel(task));
    }

    export default [
      rootSaga,
    ];
```

Comment: all sagas are canceled here: 
https://github.com/MartinCerny-awin/isomorphic-react-redux-saga-ssr/blob/master/src/server/ssr.jsx#L60

Comment: Also, the memory leak is noticeable only on the server, there are no issues on the frontend